# checkMintedSymbol

Tags: plutus, native-assets

What exactly this function is validating?

```
checkMintedSymbol :: Bool
checkMintedSymbol = case flattenValue (txInfoMint info) of
    [(cs', _, _)] -> cs' == ownCurrencySymbol ctx
    _             -> False


info :: TxInfo
info = scriptContextTxInfo ctx
```

ctx is a `ScriptContext`

Comment: At first glance, it appears to be some kind of redundancy. But I think it's used to ensure that the `CurrencySymbol` of the token (or `Value`) being minted is the same as the `CurrencySymbol` associated with the Validator/Minting Policy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It validates whether the minted value matches `ownCurrencySymbol` which in turn is a hash of the validator/minting policy.

The `checkMintedSymbol` function might be redundant as you cannot mint arbitrary currency without providing matching validator/minting policy.

Edit based on comments: it isn't redundant if there are multiple minting policies in the transaction and it ensures only one kind of currency is being minted.

Comment: It's not exactly redundant. It is saying you are only minting one kind (typically you can mint with other policies in the same tx, so in a way this is over-constrained), and it is also saying it doesn't care about the token name (as long as it's all the same) or the amount minted.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense now since the validator sees all the mints of the tx not only its "own".